Can I enforce required fields in firestore documents through a javascript class?
I'm aware that I can use firebase security rules to enforce required fields in documents. However, rather than writing the security rules, I'd like to just write a class and ensure that my document data follow this schema. Is this possible?

There is no way to enforce a schema for your Firestore documents in client-side JavaScript. While your code may be passing through that layer, malicious users can take the configuration data of your project and bypass the layer. While something like Firebase App Check can help reduce such abuse, it can't really rule it out.
That is the reason why all such schema checks must happen server-side, which you can either do:

in Firebase's security rules, as those are enforced on the server.
in server-side code, but at that stage you'll need to disable writing from the client-side code in your security rules.


That makes sense. I can write from the backend solely. How can I have one JS file that automatically exports rules to firebase ?

That sounds like a different question, so I recommend posting it separately. That gives others a chance to answer, and also gives you a chance to provide enough context.

I think it's the same question. In order for a class to enforce firebase security rules, firebase would need to have a way to automatically export rules.

Your question was "Can I enforce required fields in firestore documents through a javascript class?", which I answered here. "How can I have one JS file that automatically exports rules to firebase ?" is another question. It may be the same problem/use-case to you, they're quite different questions. ¯_(ツ)_/¯
